# Работа со слоем активных областей на стороне клиента

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Задача: хочу работать со слоем активных областей на стороне клиента.
Код здесь. Пример сильно упростил:

https://jsfiddle.net/lav_coder/yngfzsgk/

Проблема: не открывается baloon и не меняет свою форму курсор.

В документации сказано, что в ObjectSource можно передать функцию:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/hotspot.ObjectSource-docpage/

Рабочих примеров передачи функции как в данном примере, нигде не нашел.

```
var objSource = new ymaps.hotspot.ObjectSource(function (tileNumber, zoom) {
        var id = tileNumber[0] + '_' + tileNumber[1] + '_' + zoom;
        // Сюда заходим успешно
        console.log('getTileUrlHotspot: ' + id);

        return {
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                    "type": "Feature",

                    "properties": {
                        "hintContent": "Содержимое текстовой подсказки.",
                        "balloonContentBody": "Содержимое балуна.",
                        "balloonContentHeader": "Заголовок балуна.",
                        "balloonContentFooter": "Нижняя часть балуна.",

                        "HotspotMetaData": {
                            "id": id,                                
                            "RenderedGeometry": {
                                "type": "ConvexPolygon",
                                "coordinates": [[[0, 0], [0, 256], [256, 256], [256, 0], [0, 0]]]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        };
    }),        
    hotspotLayer = new ymaps.hotspot.Layer(objSource, {cursor: 'help'});
```

Answer (score 1):

в документации указано что tileUrlTemplate может быть функцией. Но эта функция должна возвращать строку а не объект (этот параметр подробно описан в классе Layer (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Layer-docpage/):

> Функция-шаблон получает на вход три параметра:
>
> tileNumber - массив из двух чисел, номера тайла по x и y;  tileZoom -
>   уровень масштабирования;  Возвращает строку-URL.

Вы передаете функцию которая возвращает объект. Апи делает запросы на урлы вида: https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/[object%20Object]?callback=id_152647247914191591782

Если я не ошибаюсь АПИ не имеет стандартной возможности реализации генерации хотспота на клиенте.